# Region Proposal Network & Anchor Box Implementation

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

I am working with R-CNN and I want to understand its working from its core and implement it. The Issue that I came across is, what is Region Proposal Network and how to implement it. From What I understand RPN take feature map from the feature extraction models like vgg16 and also have different anchor boxes of different scales and ratios but what comes next what do I do with the feature map and anchor boxes.

I tried google but all I could get is vague idea about how it works but i cant understand it and code it. Looking for a Coding solution

Anchor box issue :

I am using the following code to create anchor boxes here anc_pts_x, anc_pts_y are x and y coordinates of the anchor box center and anc_scales, anc_ratios is the scale & ratio. Is there any other method to get the anchor box because this take too much time to create anchor boxes.

```
def gen_anc_base(anc_pts_x, anc_pts_y, anc_scales, anc_ratios, out_size):
n_anc_boxes = len(anc_scales) * len(anc_ratios)
anc_base = np.zeros((1, len(anc_pts_x) 
                          , len(anc_pts_y), n_anc_boxes, 4)) # shape - [1, Hmap, Wmap, n_anchor_boxes, 4]

for ix, xc in enumerate(tqdm(anc_pts_x)):
    for jx, yc in enumerate(anc_pts_y):
        anc_boxes = np.zeros((n_anc_boxes, 4))
        c = 0
        for i, scale in enumerate(anc_scales):
            for j, ratio in enumerate(anc_ratios):
                w = scale * ratio
                h = scale
                
                xmin = xc - w / 2
                ymin = yc - h / 2
                xmax = xc + w / 2
                ymax = yc + h / 2

                anc_boxes[c, :] = tf.Variable([xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax])
                c += 1

        anc_base[:, ix, jx, :] = tf.clip_by_value(anc_boxes,[0,0,0,0],[out_size[0],out_size[1],out_size[0],out_size[1]])
        
return anc_base
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example RPN definition. The anchors are predefined different sized rectangles, covering the whole input image. So you create those earlier. Here in the RPN you have to know the number of the anchors, to be able to predict to all of them. (That is how you reshape your RPN output layers.) The RPN predicts 4 coordinates, and a label to each anchor, thats why it has two output layers.

```
def rpnN(featuremap):
    #RPN modell
    
    initializer = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal(seed=None)
    input_= tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[None, None, featuremap.shape[-1]], name="rpn_INPUT")

    shared = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', strides=1, name='rpn_conv_shared',kernel_initializer=initializer)(input_)
    # 5*2:  5 different size * 1 scale anchor, 2 label probabilities
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(5*1*2 , (1, 1), padding='valid', activation='linear',name='rpn_class_raw',kernel_initializer=initializer)(shared) 

    rpn_class_logits = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda t: tf.reshape(t, [tf.shape(t)[0], -1, 2]))(x)
    rpn_probs = tf.keras.layers.Activation("softmax", name="rpn_class_xxx")(rpn_class_logits) # --> BG/FG

    # Bounding box refinement. [batch, H, W, depth] 5*4:  5 different size * 1 scale anchor, 4 delta coordinates
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(5*1*4, (1, 1), padding="valid", activation='linear', name='rpn_bbox_pred',kernel_initializer=initializer)(shared) 

    # Reshape to [batch, anchors, 4]
    rpn_bbox = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda t: tf.reshape(t, [tf.shape(t)[0], -1, 4]))(x)
    outputs = [rpn_class_logits, rpn_probs, rpn_bbox]
    rpnN = tf.keras.models.Model(input_, outputs, name="RPN")

    return rpnN
```

Regarding the anchor boxes, you can generate those once, in the beginning of training, as that is just a list of coordinates. You can reuse that, no need to generate that for each input.

Comment: What would be the training dataset look like. I have a Anchor boxes list which is quite big should i use all of the boxes of have some threshold and take only few.

Comment: could you also help me with the updated question. I also have issue with anchor box creation.

Comment: You will predict to all the anchor boxes, but not necessarily use all the predictions in the loss function.

Comment: Regarding the anchor boxes, you can generate those once, in the beginning of training, as that is just a list of coordinates. You can reuse that, no need to generate that for each input.